# Not allowing the negative values using keys

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

In my application i have ck editor with some text in it. The text is strike of and this strike off text is selected by the user using `F1`,`F2`,`F3` AND `F4` keys.

if user selects some text that is striked of using F1 key on selecting the same text multiple times using f4 key the occurrences goes to negative. they should not go to negative and should stop at zero. below is the screen shot on pressing f4 continuously. minor row coinsurance becomes negative and sometimes PGS row become negative. they should not become negative and should stop at zero. how can i do this?

below is the javascript code for F3 and F4 keys

```
 if (event.data.$.keyCode == 114) {                             
                             label = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMinorOccurences');
                             m = label.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
                             value = parseInt(m[2], 10);
                             value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
                             if (start_element.$.innerHTML.search(/{.*}/) >= 0) {
                                 var index = start_element.$.innerHTML.search(/{.*}/);
                                 var str = null;
                                 if (index != -1) {
                                     str = start_element.$.innerHTML;
                                     if (start_element.$.innerHTML.search("{0.5}") >= 0) {
                                         label.textContent = m[1] + (value - 1);
                                         var txt = str.replace(/{.*}/, "");
                                         start_element.$.innerHTML = txt;
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                                         return;
                                     }
                                     else if (start_element.$.innerHTML.search("{1.0}") >= 0) {
                                         lblOther = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMajorOccurences');
                                         mOther = lblOther.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
                                         valOther = parseInt(mOther[2], 10);
                                         valOther = isNaN(valOther) ? 0 : valOther;
                                         lblOther.textContent = mOther[1] + (valOther - 1);
                                         var txt = str.replace(/{.*}/, "");
                                         start_element.$.innerHTML = txt;
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffff66'); start_element.appendText("{0.5}");
                                         label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
                                         return;
                                     }
                                     else if (start_element.$.innerHTML.search("{3.0}") >= 0) {
                                         lblOther = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblCriticalOccurences');
                                         mOther = lblOther.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
                                         valOther = parseInt(mOther[2], 10);
                                         valOther = isNaN(valOther) ? 0 : valOther;
                                         lblOther.textContent = mOther[1] + (valOther - 1);
                                         var txt = str.replace(/{.*}/, "");
                                         start_element.$.innerHTML = txt;
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffff66'); start_element.appendText("{0.5}");
                                         label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
                                         return;
                                     }
                                     else (start_element.$.innerHTML.search("{0.25}") >= 0)
                                     {
                                         lblOther = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblPGSOccurences');
                                         mOther = lblOther.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
                                         valOther = parseInt(mOther[2], 10);
                                         valOther = isNaN(valOther) ? 0 : valOther;
                                         lblOther.textContent = mOther[1] + (valOther - 1);
                                         var txt = str.replace(/{.*}/, "");
                                         start_element.$.innerHTML = txt;
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffff66'); start_element.appendText("{0.5}");
                                         label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
                                         return;
                                     }    
                                 }
                             }
                             else {
                                 start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffff66'); start_element.appendText("{0.5}");
                                 label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
                             }
                         }
                         if (event.data.$.keyCode == 115) {
                             label = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblPGSOccurences');
                             m = label.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
                             value = parseInt(m[2], 10);
                             value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
                             if (start_element.$.innerHTML.search(/{.*}/) >= 0) {
                                 var index = start_element.$.innerHTML.search(/{.*}/);
                                 var str = null;
                                 if (index != -1) {
                                     str = start_element.$.innerHTML;
                                     if (start_element.$.innerHTML.search("{0.5}") >= 0) {
                                         label.textContent = m[1] + (value - 1);
                                         var txt = str.replace(/{.*}/, "");
                                         start_element.$.innerHTML = txt;
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                                         return;
                                     }
                                     else if (start_element.$.innerHTML.search("{1.0}") >= 0) {
                                         lblOther = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMajorOccurences');
                                         mOther = lblOther.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
                                         valOther = parseInt(mOther[2], 10);
                                         valOther = isNaN(valOther) ? 0 : valOther;
                                         lblOther.textContent = mOther[1] + (valOther - 1);
                                         var txt = str.replace(/{.*}/, "");
                                         start_element.$.innerHTML = txt;
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#0bff01'); start_element.appendText("{0.25}");
                                         label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
                                         return;
                                     }
                                     else if (start_element.$.innerHTML.search("{3.0}") >= 0) {
                                         lblOther = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblCriticalOccurences');
                                         mOther = lblOther.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
                                         valOther = parseInt(mOther[2], 10);
                                         valOther = isNaN(valOther) ? 0 : valOther;
                                         lblOther.textContent = mOther[1] + (valOther - 1);
                                         var txt = str.replace(/{.*}/, "");
                                         start_element.$.innerHTML = txt;
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#0bff01'); start_element.appendText("{0.25}");
                                         label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
                                         return;
                                     }
                                     else (start_element.$.innerHTML.search("{0.5}") >= 0)
                                     {
                                         lblOther = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMinorOccurences');
                                         mOther = lblOther.textContent.match(/^(.*?)(\d+)$/);
                                         valOther = parseInt(mOther[2], 10);
                                         valOther = isNaN(valOther) ? 0 : valOther;
                                         lblOther.textContent = mOther[1] + (valOther - 1);
                                         var txt = str.replace(/{.*}/, "");
                                         start_element.$.innerHTML = txt;
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#ffffff');
                                         start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#0bff01'); start_element.appendText("{0.25}");
                                         label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
                                         return;
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                             else {
                                 start_element.setStyle('background-color', '#0bff01'); start_element.appendText("{0.25}");
                                 label.textContent = m[1] + (value + 1)
                             }
                         }
```

mainly it comes when i repeatedly use F4 key on the text that is already selected using other key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop at zero you need to check the current value using a simple if condition or you can use logical operator to reduce number of lines in code.

```
(value && value - 1)
```

The above code returns `0` if value is `0` otherwise decremented value of it. It's because `0` is falsy value and further execution is not done and just it returns. The resultant code would be like :

```
label.textContent = m[1] +  (value && value - 1)
```

---

So wherever you are decrements the value do the same. Or you can use ternary operator or simple if conditions to check. For example :

```
if(value != 0) value--; // decrements value if not 0 
label.textContent = m[1] + value; // update with the value
```